# Visual Studio 2019 Exception at Run (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I face an error when I run VS2019 (Professional). After loading the solution a message appears at the top of the window and it says `Visual Studio ran into an unexpected problem. You may need to reaload the solution if you continute to see error. [Open log file]`.

I had this error at version 16.1 and I couldn't find a solution therefore I uninstalled it and re-installed with version 16.2.2 but problem still occurs.

If you ask why this is important? Well, Visual Studio Installer says

> You haven't installed anything yet

...but I just did and installer can't detect it. So, I can't update my VS. This is the main problem for me. I assume, VS Installer is handling update of VS.

Thanks!

Log file content:

```
=====================
20.08.2019 01:46:38
Recoverable
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.ISetupConfiguration.GetInstanceForCurrentProcess()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<IsPrereleaseAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<IsPreviewSDKInUseAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<CheckCompatibilityAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<<InitializeAsync>b__40_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectMultiThreadedService.<>c__DisplayClass32_1.<<Fork>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<SubmitErrorReport>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Guard>g__action|0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func'1 , Func'2 , Func'2 ) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070490): Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.ISetupConfiguration.GetInstanceForCurrentProcess()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<IsPrereleaseAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<IsPreviewSDKInUseAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<CheckCompatibilityAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<<InitializeAsync>b__40_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectMultiThreadedService.<>c__DisplayClass32_1.<<Fork>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<SubmitErrorReport>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Guard>g__action|0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func'2 , Func'2 )<---

===================
```

Comment: I am getting the same problem, also when opening any project with VS 2019 Professional. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, still waiting.

Comment: About a week ago I completely removed and reinstalled VS 2019 due to this issue, which left me unable to modify or update. I deleted the install cache again - this time because of Microsoft having said that the issue was fixed. It is not fixed. I'm back in the same situation I was in - unable to modify or update VS 2019, except this time it's version 16.7.3. I do not understand why removing a cache folder is breaking things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing installer cache causes the error.

Comment: I tried adding the installer cache back and it still doesn't work

Comment: I don't know what to say but I'm pretty sure it was the reason of error and I handled by keeping the VS installer cache folder on my disk.

Comment: Good news, VS team says they fixed the issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/604336/some-errors-when-run-vs-2019.html

Answer (score 0):

I removed VS2019 and the VS installer then re-installed again with the version 16.3.1. Everything looks okay for now.

Comment: Nope, somehow it broken again. I think it's because I removed Installer cache file I don't know if it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager)
2. Delete the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\version\ComponentModelCache directory.
3. Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: This won't help.

Comment: can you give me  more detais?